# Creating array after getting variable in other function

Tags: c++, arrays, file, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

A text file looks like this:

```
3
String
String2
String3
```

I must create a function to read all the strings from text file, save them to array and then display it in main function. For example

```
void reading(int & count, string strings[]) {
ifstream fd "text.txt";
fd >> count;
for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
fd >> strings[i];
fd.close();
```

And main function:

```
int main() {
int count=0;
string strings[100];
reading(count, strings);
for (int i=0; i<count; i++) 
cout << strings[i] << endl;
```

The number of strings is written in first line of text file. How can I create an array of exactly that number? I need it to be able to access it in main/other functions. (For example function for writing into another text file).

Comment: Can you use a `std::vector<std::string>` instead of an array?

Comment: I wanna be honest with you... It's really cool helping someone but you should always consider that we have to start somewhere. That means you have to start before you can cross the finish line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case there is a super important reason to do that with an array, then use [std::new](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/), like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int reading(string** str_array, int& size,  string filename) {
    ifstream infile(filename.c_str());
    if(!infile) {
        cerr << "Unable to access file!\n";
        return -1;
    }
    int n = 0;
    infile >> size;
    try{
        *str_array = new string[size];
        string str;
        for (; n < size && infile; ++n) {
            infile >> str;
            (*str_array)[n] = str;
        }

        if (n != size)
            cerr << "ERROR, read less than " << size << " strings!!\n\n";
    } catch(bad_alloc& exc) {
        return -2;
    }
    return 0;
}


int main() {
    string* str_array = NULL;
    int size;
    if(reading(&str_array, size, "test.txt")) {
        cerr << "Din't read file, exiting...\n";
        return -1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        cout << str_array[i] << endl;

    delete [] str_array; // DO NOT FORGET TO FREE YOUR MEMORY
    str_array = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out
String
String2
String3
```

---

However, you are in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and you are not using an [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) for this?

Look how simple it is with that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int reading(vector<string>& v, string filename) {
    ifstream infile(filename.c_str());
    if(!infile) {
        cerr << "Unable to access file!\n";
        return -1;
    }
    int N = -1, n = 0;
    infile >> N;
    string str;
    for (; n < N && infile; ++n) {
        infile >> str;
        v.push_back(str);
    }

    if (n != N)
        cerr << "ERROR, read less than " << N << " strings!!\n\n";
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    vector<string> v;
    if(reading(v, "test.txt")) {
        cerr << "Din't read file, exiting...\n";
        return -1;
    }
    for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        cout << v[i] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out
String
String2
String3
```

---

Edit:

We have to pass a pointer to what we want to modify (that is, the `string*`), otherwise the changes we apply won't take place. Test it yourself, pass a `string*` as a parameter instead of `string**`, modify the body of the function and she what happens.

To get the idea, imagine we want to write to the pointer, the new address, which `new` gave us and holds the memory requested. We do write that address inside the function, but when the function terminates, we want the changes to be persistent. See my [Functions in C](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/functions-in-c/) as an example.

Comment: This is likely a homework assignment, which _IF_ it is, there are constraints on using things like that in class.

Comment: @M4rc making assumptions on this is something that should be a part of the logic the person that answers has to follow, I mean what the heck?! If it is homework, then state it. But OK, I will provide another version too then...

Comment: I agree. Ideally people would tag these things accordingly. But since when have we lived in an ideal world? The only reason I assume it's homework is because many moons ago I had to do a similar program. But then again, there are people on SO that ask people how to program an entire CLI interface.

Comment: @M4rc that's true...Nevertheless, I updated my post, is it good?

Comment: Very much so =]. Thing I love about programming -- there's more than 1 way to get to the intended end result. I would set `str_array = 0; ` after the delete statement though, but that's only because old habits die hard in checking/leaving dangling pointers.

Comment: That's true @M4rc, I will set it to `NULL`, to be the same with the initialization! ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys. That's not a homework, but its highschool related concept. The lessons regarding programming here are pretty poor, and all I have to do is create array of maximum-sized length(they give a max number) and just do work with it, but I dont like it that way, so I wanna know how can I avoid it and also get some knowledge.

Comment: By the way, why "string** str_array" instead of "string* str_array" when passing argument?

Comment: And one more question, thanks in advance! How can I can allocate a memory of string array into pointer of string? I mean it should be n amount of addresses, right?

Comment: @massacre123 good, glad that you are searching it! Don't lose faith on your course however, the may want to gentle introduce to the concepts! See my updated answer. As for the last question, it's unclear and moreover, my answer already got too big. Post a new question and comment back here with the link so I can take a look, if you like. Finally, make sure you accept one of the answers provided here. :)

Answer (score 2):

Allocate an array on the heap, like this:

```
std::string* stringArr = new std::string[(place amout of strings here)];
```

and *don't forget to delete* it at the end of main()

```
delete stringArr[];
```

Variables / arrays on the heap are dynamic so the size doesn't have to be fixed!

`std::string*` → This is a pointer that points to the address of the beginning of this array in your memory. (Just to let your computer know where it is)

`stringArr` → the name of the array

`new` → allocates new memory

`std::string[size]` → says how much to allocate

I've seen some answers that were talking about "vectors". If you wanna use them you could have a look at this page for more info! →
[Vector documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/?kw=vector)

Comment: You should use a vector instead, as it will take care of managing memory for you.

Comment: @Kariem It would but before you should get to know a vector you should learn the basics! Cause a vector uses memory on the heap

Comment: +1 - Understanding the values of fundamentals behind how vectors, maps, etc. work is far more relevant than simply following the mob mentality of throwing a STL container at everything.

Comment: @tistCoder Of course it uses memory on the heap.... I said it manages the memory for you, so when it goes out of scope it will release the memory on the heap that it has allocated.

Comment: @M4rc Thanks for that. It looks like it's his homework and the matter of them is to learn an understand

Comment: @M4rc you can both understand the fundamentals and follow good practice. They're not both mutually exclusive. A more comprehensive answer could have explained heap memory and vectors.

Comment: @Kariem you did not understand it? I guess you started crawling earlier than walking... same goes here. I would recommend a vector as well but he is a beginner and that means learning

Comment: @Kariem you are not wrong. However, inference by the basicness of his question tells me that he doesn't understand C/C++ underlying concepts, such as linked lists, dynamic memory allocation and destruction, as well as scope. To give him a container that early and spoil him on that, seems to breed an _almost_ lazy mentality we later see here when people have multi-threaded apps with containers everywhere and valgrind/gdb lines 3 pages long. Not that people aren't exceptions to the rules; but half of being an expert in something is making every mistake you can.

Answer (score 0):

use a vector

```
#include <vector>
#include<fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void reading(int & count, vector<string> * strings) {
    ifstream fd("text.txt");
    fd >> count;
    string T;
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        fd >> T;
        strings->push_back(T);
    }
    fd.close();
}

int main() {
    int count=0;
    vector<string> strings;
    reading(count, &strings);
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) 
        cout << strings[i] << endl;
 }
```